# How to save the image fetched from DOCX by PHP using ZipArchive

Tags: php

**Brief description:** I have a Docx file. I have done a simple code in PHP which extracts the images in that file and display it on the page.

**What I want to achieve:** I want that these images should be saved beside my php file with the same name and format.

My folder has `sample.docx` (which has images), `extract.php` (which extracts the images from docx) and `display.php`

Below is the code of `extract.php`

```
<?php    
/*Name of the document file*/
$document = 'sample.docx';

/*Function to extract images*/ 
function readZippedImages($filename) {

    /*Create a new ZIP archive object*/
    $zip = new ZipArchive;

    /*Open the received archive file*/
    if (true === $zip->open($filename)) {
        for ($i=0; $i<$zip->numFiles;$i++) {

            /*Loop via all the files to check for image files*/
            $zip_element = $zip->statIndex($i);                

            /*Check for images*/
            if(preg_match("([^\s]+(\.(?i)(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp))$)",$zip_element['name'])) {    

                /*Display images if present by using display.php*/
                echo "<image src='display.php?filename=".$filename."&index=".$i."' /><hr />";

            }
        }
    }
}
readZippedImages($document);
?>
```

`display.php`

```
<?php
/*Tell the browser that we want to display an image*/
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');        

/*Create a new ZIP archive object*/
$zip = new ZipArchive;

/*Open the received archive file*/
if (true === $zip->open($_GET['filename'])) {    
/*Get the content of the specified index of ZIP archive*/
echo $zip->getFromIndex($_GET['index']);
}

$zip->close();
?>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You forgot to mention your problem.

Comment: I want that these images should be saved beside my php file with the same name and format but i dont know how to do that, thats my  problem

Comment: you can successfully find the filename / path for the images?

Comment: for now i am not saving it anywhere, i want to do that, can you guide please

Comment: if image is found, save it, what will be the code here - `if(preg_match("([^\s]+(\.(?i)(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp))$)",$zip_element['name'])) {  `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not sure that you need to open the zip archive multiple times like this - especially when another instance is already open but I'd be tempted to try something like the following - I should stress that it is totally untested though.

Updated after testing:
There is no need to use `display.php` if you do like this - seems to work ok on different `.docx` files. The data returned by `$zip->getFromIndex` yields the raw image data ( so I discovered )so passing that in a query string is not possible due to the length. I tried to avoid opening/closing the zip archive unnecessarily hence the approach below which adds the raw data to the output array and the image is then displayed using this base64 encoded data inline.

```
<?php    
    #extract.php

    $document = 'sample.docx';

    function readZippedImages($filename) {
        $paths=[];
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        if( true === $zip->open( $filename ) ) {
            for( $i=0; $i < $zip->numFiles;$i++ ) {
                $zip_element = $zip->statIndex( $i );
                if( preg_match( "([^\s]+(\.(?i)(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp))$)", $zip_element['name'] ) ) {
                    $paths[ $zip_element['name'] ]=base64_encode( $zip->getFromIndex( $i ) );
                }
            }
        }
        $zip->close();
        return $paths;
    }
    $paths=readZippedImages( $document );





    /* to display & save the images */
    foreach( $paths as $name => $data ){
        $filepath=__DIR__ . '/' . $name;
        $dirpath=pathinfo( $filepath, PATHINFO_DIRNAME );
        $ext=pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
        if( !file_exists( $dirpath ) )mkdir( $dirpath,0777, true );
        if( !file_exists( $filepath ) )file_put_contents( $filepath, base64_decode( $data ) );

        printf('<img src="data:image/%s;base64, %s" />', $ext, $data );
    }
?>
```

Comment: hii, can you please share screen and see for 5 mins, may be i can close thiss, above script didnt worked

Comment: I did say it was untested. When you say "didn't worked" - what did or did not happen?

Comment: can i share anydesk

Comment: I suspect that your code doesnt read the `.docx` file and find any images ~ should have read better yesterday. Please explain without `anydesk`

Comment: i only want my file to be saved on hard disk , thats all, my code displays the pic, your code doesnt display and doesnt save on disk, shall i provide you the docx file if yu wanna test in your enviornment

Comment: this is the docx file-  we.tl/t-NuK2NsAqls

Comment: It worked, thanks, i want to understand how is it giving an index no. to the images ?? as while inserting the text in db i need to know which image is for which column, any idea how do i co relate them ?, as now my document has 5 images, i need to know, which image is from which column

Comment: there is no code here that does any database inserts/updates so hard to answer. Where / how are you adding image name to db??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205583/discussion-between-user2828442-and-ramraider).

Comment: My word file has many columns, each column has some text and few will have text and image
Current i have reached to a point where i am getting the data and i am able to split it line wise , let me show you some screenshots
1. My word file - imgur.com/KSY9rOg
2. After reading data from docx file, i am able to split it line wise, now if i can get this array no. , i'll be able to know to which text this image belongs and i can then plan to save it accordingly - imgur.com/Z4g08W8